# Send-to-Messenger Plugin does not send message to user

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/send-to-messenger

I have searched over net for the issue but didn't find any solution for it. I have created "Send to Messenger" button for my website integration and for that i have successfully created application in Facebook developer.

I have also added "Messenger" product in application and it is all working fine. My application is in live environment.

The problem is that when the user clicked on "Send to Messenger" button the login dialog box is open for authentication but after login they have not receive any message in their account.

below is my simple code which i have used to get Send to messenger button.

```
<script type="text/ecmascript"> 
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
        FB.init({ 
                appId: "appid", 
                xfbml: true, 
                version: "v2.6" 
        }); 
    }; 
    (function(d, s, id){ 
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
              if (d.getElementById(id)) { 
                return; 
              } 
              js = d.createElement(s); 
              js.id = id; 
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"; 
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 

</script> 

<div class="fb-send-to-messenger" messenger_app_id="appid" page_id="pageid" data-ref="" color="white" size="large"> </div>
```

Is there any other extra setting for that? 
Please Help us to short out this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: All that plugin does, is trigger an authentication event to your webhook. What happens after that, is up to your bot.

Comment: @CBroe     Thanks for your reply,

I have not enough knowledge about what to set up in webhook file. So i have just put one folder named webhook on our secure domain and create index file in it.
And put below code in it. to configure webhook in app. 

<?php
$challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
$verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];

if ($verify_token === 'mytoken') {
echo $challenge;
}
?>

is there anything more required in it?

Comment: That is only the part of setting up your webhook to receive updates from Facebook ... but if that is all, the whole rest is missing - the part where your bot script actually communicates with the user. (Are you sure you have an actual understanding of how that whole Messenger Platform thing works? Sounds rather not like it so far.)

Comment: @CBroe I am php developer and i didn't find any usefull script to setup in webhook. I dont know what to setup in rest script for bot.Could you please help me.how to set up rest.i just want to sent welcome message to user when they successfully click on button.

Comment: Implementing how your app handles the data it gets send via the webhook is the main part of the job here. It is up to you to define what your bot is supposed to do, and how it reacts to different user inputs. Going into that here in detail would be way too broad. You must have a bit more of a concept for your bot then just sending users a welcome message anyway, because that in itself is hardly anything Facebook would approve in review.

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. The Send-to-Messenger plugin is only one of several entry points for a messenger conversation with a bot. You should really have a bot with defined functionality first, before you start thinking about what to do at the different entry points.

Comment: @CBroe I have updated the script for webhook file as below but this is still not working could you please help me              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689562/facebook-send-to-messenger-plugin-not-send-welcome-message-to-user